# How do I split up an argument string Bash-style in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I'm making a simple shell for a project, and I want argument strings to be parsed just like in Bash.

```
foo bar "hello world" fooz
```

Should become:

```
["foo", "bar", "hello world", "fooz"]
```

Etc. So far I've been using `CSV::parse_line`, setting the column separator to `" "` and `.compact`ing the output. The problems is that I must now choose whether I want to support single quotes or double quotes. `CSV` doesn't support more than a single delimiter character.

Python has a module for exactly this called `shlex`:

```
>>> shlex.split("Test 'hello world' foo")
['Test', 'hello world', 'foo']
>>> shlex.split('Test "hello world" foo')
['Test', 'hello world', 'foo']
```

Are there any hidden built in Ruby modules that can do this? Any suggestions for a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course there is: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellsplit. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby has the module [`Shellwords`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html):

```
require "shellwords"

Shellwords.shellsplit('Test "hello world" foo')
# => ["Test", "hello world", "foo"]

'Test "hello world" foo'.shellsplit
# => ["Test", "hello world", "foo"]
```

Comment: I believe it is `shellsplit`, you beat me to it!

Comment: @squiguy `Shellwords#split` is an alias for `Shellwords#shellsplit`.

Comment: After importing "shellwords" you can also do `'Test "hello world" foo'.shellsplit`

Comment: @toro2k Ah I didn't read that far down. I think it would be less confusing to use `shellsplit` over the regular string `split` IMHO.

Comment: @Codemonkey I didn't know that, however it is not even necessary to `require "shellwords"` to make it works.

Comment: @Codemonkey Ops.. I was testing on pry that already requires `Shellwords`.